# Dini derivative of the maximum of two continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given two locally Lipschitz continuous functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $i\in \{1,2\}$, let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$
f(x)=\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}.
$$
Is it true that the upper-right Dini derivative 
$$
D^+f(x,v)=\limsup_{t\to 0^+} \tfrac{1}{t}(f(x+tv)-f(x))
$$
satisfies
$$
D^+f(x,v)=\max\{D^+f_1(x,v),D^+f_2(x,v)\}
$$
for all $x,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If yes, does this also hold for the other (upper/lower left/right) Dini derivatives?

I wanted to ask, if the following identity holds:

$$D^{+} f(x,v) = \max\{D^+f_i(x,v)\mid i\in I(x)\}.$$

where $I(x)=\{i\in\{1,2\}\mid f(x)=f_i(x)\}$.

Comment: If you can spot the (subtle) difference between the original identity (still here) and the second identity (edited in recently) then it should be easy enough to answer the question.  If not, try doing it for $n=1$.